# Treinamento com JavaScript - cores

Tags: javascript

Qual problema no meu código? Creio que a lógica esteja correta!

```
<h1 id="colorchange">ESTAMOS FAZENDO TESTE DE CORES COM JAVASCRIPT!</h1>
<input type="text" name="Cor" id="whatcolor"><br /><br>
<button type="button" onclick="newcolor('whatcolor')">Mudar</button>
<script>
        function newcolor(thecolor) {
        document.getElementById('colorchange').style.color = thecolor;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Você aparentemente está definindo a cor de `colorchange` como sendo `'whatcolor'` e isso não é uma cor válida. O que tentou fazer e o que esperava que acontecesse?

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que você esteja tentando fazer algo assim:

```html
<h1 id="colorchange">ESTAMOS FAZENDO TESTE DE CORES COM JAVASCRIPT!</h1>
<input type="text" name="Cor" id="whatcolor"><br /><br>
<button type="button" onclick="newcolor('whatcolor')">Mudar</button>
<script>
  //A função recebe o id do elemento input e pega o seu valor
  function newcolor(id) {
    document.getElementById('colorchange').style.color = document.getElementById(id).value;
  }
</script>
```

Ou então pegar diretamente, sem receber o id do elemento `input`

```html
<h1 id="colorchange">ESTAMOS FAZENDO TESTE DE CORES COM JAVASCRIPT!</h1>
<input type="text" name="Cor" id="whatcolor"><br /><br>
<button type="button" onclick="newcolor()">Mudar</button>
<script>
  function newcolor() {
    document.getElementById('colorchange').style.color = document.getElementById('whatcolor').value;
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Exatamente isso que eu queria, entendi seu código.´

Só uma dúvida,

por qual motivo você teve que pegar pelo document? Sendo que o ID já estava na function.. E outro ponto, quando você chama a cor ela lê em string ou Int?


Obrigado pela sua ajuda cara, estou aprendendo bastante! :))

Comment: Não entendi, se eu não chamar pelo `document` vou chamar por onde? O id que é recebido é a string, não o elemento. O valor de `document.getElementById(id).value` sempre será uma string, até porque não existe cor só de numéricos, se quiser o vermelho, por exemplo, pode usar "#900", mas tem uma "#" na frente, assim como o rgb, rgba, hsl, etc (que terão parênteses e vírgula)

Comment: Oi Costa,
Entendi a lógica, obrigado pelo seu apoio! ;)